# Gatsby - Using Dynamic Images Inside a Component

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I have a component that works as a collapsible ui element where an image is loaded when opened. These collapsible elements are part of a list, and I need the image to be a variable since it's different on each list item.

I understand that I need to use Dynamic Images in Gatsby, since [Static Images can't use props](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage), and I need to resolve the image name from a prop.

Trying to use Dynamic Image, I'm getting "undefined" when trying to resolve the image from a prop. According to [this post](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5102#issuecomment-450851360), you can't use GraphQL inside a component that is not in the /pages directory. Instead they are suggesting the use of [Fragment](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/using-graphql-fragments/), and that's where I'm stuck trying to figure out how to use it in my specific case.

Here's what I'm trying to do in **src/components/Collapsible.js**:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";

function Collapsible({ hit, children }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const image = "../images/reference/render/" + hit.name;

  return !isOpen ? (
    <tr className="row" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
      {children}
    </tr>
  ) : (
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="4">
        <div className="material-card">
          <div>
            <h1 onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>{hit.name}</h1>
            <p>{hit.category}</p>
            <div className="thumbnail">
              <GatsbyImage image={image}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default Collapsible;
```

Somehow I'm supposed to be able to create a [Fragment](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/using-graphql-fragments/) using my GraphQl query, which looks like this:

```js
query Image {
  file(relativePath: {eq: "reference/render/image1.png"}) {
    id
    childImageSharp {
      gatsbyImageData(
        width: 300
        placeholder: NONE
        quality: 75
        layout: CONSTRAINED
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
const image = "../images/reference/render/" + hit.name;
```

Is returning a path, while when using `GatsbyImage` you need to provide a full object with `gatsbyImageData` as an `image` property. The approach will work when rendering "standard" `<img>` in the `src` attribute but not with `GatsbyImage` since your `image` variable doesn't contain the data that `GatsbyImage` needs.

Moreover, your GraphQL query fragment I'm not sure where it's used, but not in any snippet you've shared. The problem here is that you are trying to combine dynamic images with static queries, where you can't use dynamic filters: `hit.name` will be something dynamic and you cannot combine it with static queries hence they don't accept dynamic parameters.

That said, I think a valid workaround will be using a [useStaticQuery hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) to get `allFile` node with `gatsbyImageData` in it and filter the array using `hit.name` or with the `relativePath`. `allFile` will hold all your images so that you only need to filter it using JavaScript.

```
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

function Collapsible({ hit, children }) {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query allImages {
      allFile {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(
                width: 300
                placeholder: NONE
                quality: 75
                layout: CONSTRAINED
              )
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

   const image = data.allFile.edges.node.filter(node => node.relativePath === "../images/reference/render/" + hit.name) 

  return !isOpen ? (
    <tr className="row" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
      {children}
    </tr>
  ) : (
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="4">
        <div className="material-card">
          <div>
            <h1 onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>{hit.name}</h1>
            <p>{hit.category}</p>
            <div className="thumbnail">
              <GatsbyImage image={image} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

*Note: Test the query in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` before to ensure that the query is returning the correct data. Tweak the `node => node.relativePath === "../images/reference/render/" + hit.name` to match your specific filter, this is an example.*

The static query will hold your data inside `data.allFile`, there, using `hit.name` you can filter the array of images and get the needed one. This image, since it's queried and holding `gatsbyImageData`, will be a valid image to use in `GatsbyImage`

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer, and thanks for giving me a good example based on my code!

However I'm stuck on getting data.allFile.edges.node. For some reason I'm getting "undefined". I've double checked my query in GraphQl and it gives me the data I need. Also, if I get data.allFile, then it works. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Check if for some reason, in some React lifecycle data is `undefined` (breaking your code) and add the proper conditions. For example: `data?.allFile?.edges?.node`